# Optimization of MySQL perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I am currently working on a project which involves data manipulation of a MySQL database. First of all, I need to tell you that I use a perl script that is executed on the same machine. Also, I would like to say some things about the table that I am working on: The create table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `deCoupled` (
    `AA` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     ...several other fields,
     KEY `AA` (`AA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In order to optimize the way I work on the data, I create a temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_deCoupled` AS SELECT * FROM `deCoupled` ORDER BY field1,field2,...,fieldN
```

and add an auto_increment key field that I need for the data manipulation:

```
ALTER TABLE `temp_deCoupled` ADD COLUMN MY_KEY INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
ALTER TABLE `temp_deCoupled` ADD INDEX (MY_KEY)
```

I alter the table like this, because I scan the table with the query

```
SELECT COUNT(`AA`), field1, field2,..., fieldN FROM `temp_deCoupled`
GROUP BY field1, field2,..., fieldN ORDER BY field1, field2,..., fieldN
```

and I execute updates on records according to the MY_KEY field.
Unfortunately, for a record number of about 75000 records, It takes about 75 minutes on a pc
with a dual core CPU and 2gigs of ram. Also, I need to tell you that the perl script that manipulates the data does not do any complex calculations.

I tried to tune the MYSQL server and I updated the my.cnf file with the following:

```
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M
key_buffer_size = 128M
table_cache = 1024
query_cache_limit = 128M
query_cache_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_flush_method = o_DIRECT
```

I really need to lower the execution time of the script. Can anyone make any suggestions?

To be more precise about the updates I will post a sample of the code below:

```
$qSel = "SELECT COUNT(*), field1,..., fieldN FROM `temp_deCoupled` GROUP BY field1,..., fieldN ORDER BY field1,...,fieldN";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qSel);
$stmt->execute() or die "Error occurred: $DBI::errstr.\n";
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    .... *some code*...
    $q_sel_keys = "SELECT MY_KEY FROM `temp_deCoupled` WHERE field1 = value1 AND ... AND fieldN = valueN";
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare($q_sel_keys);
    $stmt1->execute() or die "Error occured: $DBI::errstr.\n";
    ...*some other code*...
    $q_Update_Records = "UPDATE `temp_deCoupled` SET field1=val_1,..., fieldN=val_N WHERE MY_KEY = key1 OR MY_KEY = key2 OR ... OR MY_KEY = keyN";
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare($q_Update_Records);
    $tmp_c = $stmt1->execute() or die "Error occured: $DBI::errstr.\n";
    ...*some final code*...
}
```

and that is the main body (in general) of the data manipulation in Perl.

Comment: Droping indices before alternation could speed things up. Maybe you should also show your Perl code so we can see how exactly you do your operations on the database.

Comment: Nothing you've shown so far explains why you're using a temp table or why you have an 'order by' in the select that creates the temp table.

Comment: Why are you adding an integer KEY when the original table already has a KEY?

Comment: I may have not made my self clear. It's not the index that is taking so long. It is the manipulation of data, from the perl script. Since I can not post code from the script online, I will tell you that it is mostly updates based on the MY_KEY field. I would like to thank you for your interest, but please read carefully before commenting. Thank you

Comment: Len Jaffe I add the temp table because I want to maintain a table on the disk that the records are ordered. I add that key because i need a unique auto-increment key for my records.

Comment: "but please read carefully before commenting" - no good deed goes unpunished.  If you won't post the code, we can't optimize it for you.

Comment: @popanik: if the table copy and reindex aren't an issue then all you have told us of relevance is that you have a table `temp_deCoupled` with an auto-incremented key and it takes too long to perform an undisclosed sequence of operations on it. How are we supposed help you with that?

Comment: @Borodin i posted that the sequence of operations relevant to the data is an update based on the MY_KEY. Also where did you see rudeness in the above quote?

Comment: So, you are finding all distinct combinations of field1,field2,...,fieldN, and updating each combination in some way?  Are you using the values of my_key from the select in the while loop in any way in "some other code", or just in the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have provided a lot of information, but not the key information (if you will excuse the pun) needed.  That is: what do the updates that take so long do?

If you are individually executing 75000 update statements, that is going to take a long time.
Try grouping them together where the operation performed by the update is the same and only the key differs, e.g. doing:

```
update temp_deCoupled set fieldx=..., fieldy=... where my_key in (?,?,?,?,...)
```

In a worst case scenario, where the updates are largely distinct, you can use another table to provide the information needed for the update.  For instance, given this table:

```
create table foo ( id int primary key, bar double );
```

where you need to multiply each bar by a different value based on id, create another table to hold the multipliers, insert them in a single request from your script, and then update:

```
create temporary table foo_multiply ( id int primary key, mult double );
insert into foo_multiply values (1,123),(2,42),(3,666),...;
update foo inner join foo_multiply using (id) set foo.bar=foo.bar * foo_multiply.mult;
```

It can be a good idea to break up the insert statements into lines no longer than 1MB or so.
In extreme cases, write the data to insert out to a file and load it with "LOAD DATA INFILE".

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. As I mentioned above, the updates are sparse and depend on the MY_KEY field. Your suggestion to group the updates is something that I have not thought of and I will try it and see how it works.

Comment: Also @ysth , do you think that the changes that I present in my post are adequate, or should I do something else?

Comment: I updated the initial post with some more information. Please, If you have time, check it out. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to lower the execution time to 12 minutes by creating the temp_deCoupled table as:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_deCoupled` ENGINE = MEMORY AS SELECT * FROM `deCoupled` ORDER BY field1,field2,...,fieldN
```

and I also did the following configuration on the my.cnf:

```
max_heap_table_size = 512M
```

I would like to thank everyone for the interest you showed.

Comment: If your data is guaranteed to fit into memory, you will be better off just reading it all into a big hash and modifying it in perl, then inserting it all into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

By default the MySQL driver commits changes to the database after each statement. This often leads to suboptimal performance when making a large number of updates.

Disabling AutoCommit mode could solve your performance problem. But as with @ystsh idea, this is more based on information you havn't provided.

Comment: I added some more information relevant to the data manipulation on the first post, from the perl script. I do not think that any more information would be relevant with the performance of the mysql server.

Comment: It is of course entirely up to you, but you have not provided any information related to per connection configuration. The most relevant per connection setting would be to enable AutoCommit, but other attributes could have a performance impact too.