How to speed up multiple column bulk updates in MySQL using python
I have some python code that reads data from a pandas Dataframe and updates multiple fields in a MySQL table using the primary key in the where clause. The "merchant_id" field is indexed. The code goes like this:
def bulk_update_current_tier(cursor, row):
    
    q = """
    update customers_merchant_map
    set loyalty_conf_id = %s, loyalty_join_date = %s, loyalty_exit_date = %s
    where merchant_id = 1818
    and id = %s
    """
    cursor.executemany(q, row)

# instantiate cursor
cursor = mydb.cursor()
print(f"Cursor instance created: {cursor}.")

start_idx = 0
batch_size = 5000 # change batch size as per requirement

counter = 0

while True:
    counter += 1
    print(f"Iteration: {counter}")
    sub_df = current_tier[start_idx:start_idx+batch_size] # dataframe can be changed here as per requirement
    
    # bulk insert logic to be added here
    rows_to_insert = [(row['tier_conf_ids'], row['tier_start_date'], row['tier_end_date'], row['customer_id']) for _, row in sub_df.iterrows()]
    
    if len(rows_to_insert) < batch_size:
        print("Number of rows are less than batchsize...")
        bulk_update_current_tier(cursor, rows_to_insert)
        print("Comitting changes...")
        mydb.commit()
        break
    
    bulk_update_current_tier(cursor, rows_to_insert) # batch update values
    start_idx += batch_size
    print("Batch inserted. Committing changes...")
    mydb.commit()
#     break
    
mydb.commit()
print("Done.")

Event though this code runs correctly, it only updates around 1000 rows per minute (there are around 5 million in total!). Any pointers on how I can speed up this process even more?
Our MySQL server is hosted on Amazon RDS.
I am already batching the rows together and running cursor.executemany() and committing once every 5k rows are updated. I've also checked that the actual addition of rows into the "rows_to_insert" list takes around 1 / 20th of a second, confirming that the process is taking time in the update query itself. Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated!!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150799
